# "It is not possible to perform this action in a template" error when publishing SG, but not its contents

Tags: templating, vbscript

I have a couple of Structure Groups for which publishing fails with the message "It is not possible to perform this action in a template". When I select the Structure Groups and Pages that are in the failing Structure Group, I can publish these without problems.

The error message sounds like one that you might get if attempting a write action from a template, but it seems unlikely that this would be the case only when publishing the containing Structure Group and not its contents.

This is an old site with the templating in VbScript, running on 8.5.

What might the cause of this be? How can I further investigate?

Comment: Have you checked the Tridion Event Log?  I would expect the logged error event to contain a Stack Trace which should provide more insight about where the problem occurs.

Comment: I agree it sounds unlikely, but have you tried changing the setting that allows templates to make changes?